# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' en petición GET con angularjs

Tags: javascript, webservice, http, angulajs, get

Estoy tratando de consumir un `web service` con el modulo `$http` de `angularjs` mi código es el siguiente:

```
getCurrentPositionByClientName: function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http({
           method: 'GET',
           url: 'http://gps.server.com/WS/WSTrack2.asmx/GetCurrentPositionByClientName?SecurityToken=0000000&ClientName=Nombre del cliente',
           headers: {
               'Content-Type':'application/xml; charset=UTF-8'
              }
       }).then(function(result){

                console.log("result", result);

                deferred.resolve(result);
       }, function(error){

                console.log("error", error);

                deferred.reject(error);
       });
       return deferred.promise;
     }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que me sale el siguiente error, al realizar la petición:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://gps.server.com/WS/WSTrack2.asmx/GetCurrentPositionByClientName?SecurityToken=0000000&ClientName=Nombre%del%cliente. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:81' is therefore not allowed access.
```

E estado haciendo pruebas con una extensión para chrome para que me funcionará pero cuando lo subí al servidor de producción me tira el mismo error y pues no es viable estar instalando la extensión en todos los navegadores que vayan a usar el sistema.

¿Hay alguna manera de solucionar este problema? y si la hay, ¿cual es?.

Comment: El webservice está respondiendo sin la cabecera que permite CORS. ¿Este webservice es tuyo, o alternativamente, tenés posibilidad de solicitar que agreguen esta cabecera? De otra forma ningún navegador moderno te va a permitir acceder a este recurso.

Comment: No es mio, es un web service que compro, entonces seria bueno pedirle a los desarrolladores del ws que modifiquen esa parte.

Comment: ya lo corri online y sale lo mismo.